# How to create a method for posting a notification in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How to create a method for posting a notification through the NSNotificationCenter and then call the method through applicationDidFinishLauching main method without any (IBAction) . I just wanted to send only a message.I also dont want the postNotification to be placed in applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching
{

 event=[[SomeClass alloc]init];

}

-(void)sendEvent:(id)sender
{
     postNotificationName:... object:---
}
```

Now i where i need to call this sendEvent method in my program.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-postNotification` method on NSNotificationCenter is what you're looking for:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // ...
   [self postNotification];
}

- (void)postNotification
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter] defaultCenter] postNotification:@"Notification"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the actual answer i wanted.